# Accessing and saving XElements in an object collection

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

I Have the following scenario, and would like some help guidance on the topic:

I Have an XML file composed of user credentials (Not for commercial use, so security is really not of any significance in this scenario) for a simple chat application. If a user subscribes to the service, his credentials should match that recorded in the XML file.

---

Code snippet of the XML file:

```
<Users>
 <User>
  <Username>Johan</Username>
  <Password>Johan123</Password>
 </User>
 <User>
  <Username>Carel</Username>
  <Password>Carel123</Password>
 </User>
  ...
  ...
</Users>
```

Then I have the following class:

```
public class Credentials
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

---

The Credentials class is merely going to be used to retrieve the List of users recorded in the XML file, as well as retrieving specific users.

I have the following code that can retrieve elements out of the XML file:

```
public List<Credentials> RetrieveUsers()
        {
            Root = XElement.Load(path + "Users.xml");
            List<Credentials> credentials = new List<Credentials>();

            var xmlResults = from element in Root.Elements().Elements()
                     select new 
                     {
                           Username = element.Element("Username").Value,
                           Password = element.Element("Password").Value
                     };

            foreach(var xmlResult in xmlResults)
            {
                Credentials temp = new Credentials();

                temp.Username = xmlResult.Username;
                temp.Password = xmlResult.Password;

                credentials.Add(temp);
            }

            return credentials;
        }
```

However, this feels redundant. I want to achieve something in the line of the following (This does not work):

```
public List<Credentials> RetrieveUsers()
        {
            Root = XElement.Load(path + "Users.xml");
            List<Credentials> credentials = new List<Credentials>();

            List<Credentials> xmlResults = from element in Root.Elements().Elements()
                select new 
                {
                       Username = element.Element("Username").Value,
                       Password = element.Element("Password").Value
                };
            return xmlResults;
        }
```

It gives me the following error:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

which makes perfect sense, as I imagine it uses IEnumerable to enumerate through the collection made by the select LINQ statement.

Any help on the matter would be appreciated, and please tell me if I'm looking at this from the wrong angle, if I can use another approach instead. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to call the `ToList` extension method to create a list. Also, you need to create `Credentials` objects rather than instances of an anonymous type. For example:

```
var xmlResults = from element in Root.Elements().Elements()
                 select new Credentials
                 {
                     Username = element.Element("Username").Value,
                     Password = element.Element("Password").Value
                 };
return xmlResults.ToList();
```

Personally I don't tend to use query expressions for simple from/select queries - I'd have written:

```
return Root.Elements().Elements() // TODO: Consider specifying the element name
           .Select(element => new Credentials
                   {
                     Username = element.Element("Username").Value,
                     Password = element.Element("Password").Value
                   })
           .ToList();
```

The advantage of using "dot notation" like this is that calling `ToList` doesn't leave you with a query expression in brackets, which always looks a bit ugly.

Comment: sure thing, wanted to clarify that I wasn't missing something

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot :) I knew it was something small that I'm overlooking. I am still a bit nervous with using lambda expressions as I'm not fully comfortable as to how it work, but I will look into it as it really visually improves the code. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: I am curious.. Using a lambda expression, can you add criteria the same as LINQ? For example '... where Username = "<username>"'?

Comment: Wahoo - I got an approved edit on a Jon Skeet post.  There must be a badge for that, right?

Comment: @Harrison: I'm afraid I've rolled back your edit - you don't need the `()` on object initializers.

Comment: @JohanAspeling: Yes, absolutely. Query expressions just compile down to calls to other methods - so you can use `.Where(x => x.Id == 10)` or whatever.

Comment: @JonSkeet I should have known better than to correct the master.  Sorry.  To clarify, don't need or can't have?

Comment: @Harrison: Don't need. You *can* do it, I just tend not to. And there's no need to apologise - I often *do* make typos, so don't let it stop you from making edits in the future :)

Comment: That is seriously awesome... I _HAVE_ to look into lambda now 0.0

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
        List<Credentials> xmlResults = Root.Elements().Elements()
            .Select(element => new Credential() {
                   Username = element.Element("Username").Value,
                   Password = element.Element("Password").Value
            })
            .ToList();
```